# Aligning a button in a date-field

Tags: extjs

I have this datepicker that i added under (by default) its 'today' button, another button. Now i'm trying to align the new button on the same line of the original button on equal distance. Any idea on how to do so?

```
xtype   : 'datefield',
format  : 'd/m/Y',
editable: false,

listeners: {
    select: {
        fn:function(){ 
            var date = ""+ this.value + "";
            var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
            var where = "";
            where = "DATE_OF_ADMISSION = '" + newdate + "'";
            loadData(where);
        } 
    },
    render: function() {
        var me = this,
            trigger = me.trigger;

        trigger.on('click',
            function() {
                if (me.menu.picker) {
                    var btn = new Ext.Button({
                        renderTo: me.menu.picker.getEl().child('td.x-date-bottom', true),
                        text: 'Reset',
                        handler: function() {
                            resetOriginalValue();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            null,
            {
                single: true
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: [Please make a fiddle showing your problem.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/) I was unable to reproduce your issue with your code - it threw all kind of errors way before I could look into your design issue.